# Only view 5 rows for 'View as DataFrame' in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, intellij-14

When I click 'View as DataFrame' in PyCharm Debugger, the out put is like this.

[image]

My PyCharm version is 2020.1 and I am using Windows machine. Is there any way to maximize the number of rows viewed in the viewer window in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known regression, see the ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41601